# NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.hash.Hashing.crc32c

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, guava, spark-submit

I'm trying to access Google cloud storage from my spark code. But I'm getting the following error on creating a file in GCS.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.hash.Hashing.crc32c()Lcom/google/common/hash/HashFunction;
> at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:169)

When I try to access the same method in my code, it doesn't show any error in my IDE. I'm facing this issue only on `spark-submit`.

I'm trying to create a file in GCS using:

```
val storage: Storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder.setCredentials(credentials).build.getService
val blobId = BlobId.of(bucket, outputFile)
val blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType(contentType).build
storage.create(blobInfo, data)
```

This is my `pom.xml`.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
   <version>1.113.1</version>
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
           <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
           <artifactId>failureaccess</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
           <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>30.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

**EDIT #1:** The same code is working fine through `spark-shell`. It is failing only when tried with `spark-submit`. I've tried excluding the `guava` artifact from every dependency in the pom. Still, it is failing with the same error.

**EDIT #2:** I'm using the following command for `spark-submit`.

```sh
spark-submit \
  --master yarn \
  --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=${JAR_FILE} \
  --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=${JAR_FILE} \
  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
  --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
  --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
  --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="${EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS}" \
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC \
  --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=80 \
  --num-executors 80 \
  --executor-cores 5 \
  --executor-memory 16G \
  --driver-memory 6G \
  --name ${APP_NAME} \
  --class ${CLASS_NAME} \
  --deploy-mode cluster ${JAR_FILE}
```

and this command for entering `spark-shell`.

```sh
spark-shell --files ${JAR_FILE} \
  --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=${JAR_FILE} \
  --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=${JAR_FILE} \
  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC \
  --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="${EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS}" \
  --num-executors 80 \
  --executor-cores 5 \
  --executor-memory 16G \
  --driver-memory 6G
```

Comment: have you created the uberjar? or just submit the generated jar?

Comment: @AlexOtt, i'm submitting the uber jar.

Comment: what is the spark version?

Comment: @AlexOtt, Spark version is `2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935550/gae-cloud-storage-guava-nosuchmethoderror-on-appspot